# I want to define some properties for an object by myself

Tags: python, scripting, objects, properties

```
def properties(object):
for object in bpy.data.collections["furniture"].all_objects:
    object.orient_vector = object.matrix_local[0:3][0][0:3][:]
object.object_front_name = object.name.split("_")[0]
object.object_last_name = object.name.split("_")[1]
```

Above showed is a part of my work, I'm trying to custom some unique properties for one object. But seems not work when I entered "object.xxx = 1" and printed.

(by the way object can be called solely right? Don't need to type "bpy.xxx.object")

Comment: object['my_prop'] = 'hello'

Comment: TypeError: 'type' object does not support item assignment. Seems object class don't have __setitem__ @XY

Comment: don't use `object` as a variable. this is python's general class designed for other purposes. you can assign `bpy.context.object` to some variable like `obj` (instead of `object`) so you can use it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import bpy

oj = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
oj["my_prop"] = "hello"

print("Object name: ", oj.name)
print(oj["my_prop"])
```

[image]

Comment: if the properties is not data version? Do I still have to define it in bpy.data.object instead of context?

Comment: if your active object is "Cube", that means bpy.context.object and bpy.data.objects["Cube"] are same.